# AutoMapper.pdb not loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, umbraco, umbraco7

I just run my application and start having this error `AutoMapper.pdb not loaded` error

[image]

I don't know what I did and how I can remove this. It seems it doesn't do anything major as I can continue with my application it's just that it's annoying to keep on pressing the continue button. Is there a way to remove or fix this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and running an Umbraco application.

Comment: The "PDB not loaded" is not the error, the NullRefException also in the screenshot is. Apparently the application uses Automapper which runs into an problem, please post the details on the exception (stacktrace+relevant code)

Comment: @Lennart thanks for the reply. I tried to reset my VS settings and the error just went away. Closing the ticket now

Comment: @MadzQuestioning can you show me how to reset VS settings plz